# Skobbler iOS crash during navigation

Tags: skmaps

I'm using the Skobbler iOS SDK (2.5.1) in a native iOS app, running on iOS 9/iPhone 6.

On a beta tester's device, at some point in navigation, there's a crash deep in C++ code:

`std::__1::__tree<std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int>, std::__1::__map_value_compare<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int>, std::__1::less<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, true>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int> > >::destroy(std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int>, void*>*) + 2571784`

This is coming out of OpenGL which is only used by Skobbler in my project.

As this hasn't been reproduced "in the lab" I'm writing to see if anyone has had a similar experience/crash or if this raises an inkling of recognition. I appreciate any advice you may have.

Comment: We are aware of similar issues regarding those GLStateMachine issues.  We've created a hotfix for these crashes, so please contact us at dev@telenav.com and we'll share it with you also.

Answer (score 1):

We've created a hotfix for these crashes regarding those GLStateMachine issues and we've shared it on our forum: http://forum.skobbler.com/showthread.php/7507-Fix-for-quot-iOS-9-2-crashes-quot-the-log-pointing-to-the-GLStateMachine